# AJV validator always true, even with garbage input

Tags: json, ajv

I have three schemas

```
{
  "$id": "app.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title": "app",
  "description": "Root configuration object",
  "properties": {
    "views" : {
      "description": "The pages in the application",
      "type" : "object",
      "properties" : {
        "summary" : {
          "$ref": "view.schema.json"
        }
      },
      "additionalItems": {
        "$ref": "view.schema.json"
      },
      "required" : ["summary"]
    }
  },
  "required": ["views"]
}
```

```
{
  "$id" : "component.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title" : "component",
  "properties": {
    "type" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "enum" : ["container"]
    }
  },
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "type" : {
          "enum" : ["container"]
        },
        "direction" : {
          "enum" : ["horizontal", "vertical"]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
  "$id" : "view.schema.json",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "title" : "view",
  "additionalProperties" : {
    "description": "The components in this view",
    "$ref" : "component.schema.json"
  }
}
```

I successfully load these files and add them to to the ajv instance with `addSchema`. However, whenever I pass any data to `validate`, even invalid gibberish, validate always returns true.

When I examine the `_schemas` property on the instance, all of the schemas are present and look like what their json files define.

Testing the equivalent using the `ajv-cli` (`ajv -s schemas/app.schema -r schemas/view.schema -r schemas/component.schema -d plugin.json`)
fails with an error. I copy-pasted the body of the validator function into a scratch file in my IDE and into a jsfiddle and it work in both of those environments.

Answer (score -1):

You need to JSON parse your data before passing it into validate function.